# Changing element background color with jQuery .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so my javascript code is creating a list of table items, however I want it to able to change the color of the row according to what selections were made, each time a new item is added. Here's my code

```
   if ( valid ) {
        $( "#tasks2 tbody" ).append( "<div id='taskList'><ul class='taskScreen2'><tr>" +
          "<td><h1>"  + type.val() + "</h1></td>"+"<td class='title'><h3>"+  title.val() + " </td>"  +"<td>"+ wordcount.val() + "</h3></td>"  +"<td><p>"+  description.val() + "</p></td>"  + "<td>"+ deadline.val() + "</td>"+
        "</tr></ul></div>"
                + "<script> if ($('#type').val()=='Dissertation')"
        + "{document.getElementById('taskList').style.backgroundColor = 'red';} </script>"
   );
```

This only changes the color of the top item while any new ones remains the same. I want it to change the bg colour of new item whenever it is added. I tried including the function both inside and outside the .append but it did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context, use class instead. BTW, set `background-color ` directly in CSS, if possible

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it gives me this error "Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined"

Comment: You have to use relevant method regarding targeting class

Comment: Here's what I am using `document.getElementsByClassName("taskList").style.backgroundColor = "red";` is there anything wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You are appending divs all with same ID's(which is wrong).Use class instead and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However now I am getting this error message "Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (valid) {
    var ids=$("#tasks2, #taskList, #type");
    for (var x=0; x<ids.length; x++) {
        ids.get(x).className=ids.get(x).id;
    }
    ids.attr("id", "");
    $(".tasks2 tbody").append("\
        <div class='taskList'><ul class='taskScreen2'><tr>"
        +"<td><h1>"
        +type.val()
        +"</h1></td>"
        +"<td class='title'><h3>"
        +title.val()
        +"</td>"
        +"<td>"
        +wordcount.val()
        +"</h3></td>"
        +"<td><p>"
        +description.val()
        +"</p></td>"
        +"<td>"
        +deadline.val()
        +"</td>"
        +"</tr></ul></div>"

        // Reply to Egidijus Poškus's comment: Here's how to do it!

        +"<script>$(\".type[value='Dissertation']\").css('background-color', 'red');$(\".type[value='Report']\").css('background-color', 'blue');\
    ");
}
```

Comment: Used `+"<script>if($('.type').val()=='Dissertation')"
        +"{$('.taskList').css('background-color', 'red');}</script>"` it worked, thanks so much!

Comment: One more question, can I make it to allow several different colours, for example if type is set to dissertation color is red if it is set to report color is blue. And have list of tasks with different colors?

Comment: Thank you very much! In the last comment you made, where do I specify what part of the document should be recolored (taskList in this case) by the way how do I prevent the color change of all items when for example 1st item was dissertation which was red, then report which is should be blue by itself but it dyes my whole item list into blue. Sorry for asking so much I am quite new to this.

Comment: Don't know, it does partially work, I mean when I add dissertation and report to the list only the colour of the latter is displayed and every other item is dyed the same colour.

Comment: I accidentally made a syntax error. Does it work now?

Comment: I get this error `[ids.get(...)].attr is not a function`

Comment: Now nothing happens, the data gets through but bg color does not change. Aren't you supposed to define where to change the bg color (taskList in this case) in the bottom <script>  tag? By the way thank you so much for helping me out @Narawa Games

Comment: Do you want to change the Dissertation or the Report, or do you want to change the whole TaskList?